# Replacing User Input with Prepared Statement in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to overwrite a user's input and replace it with whatever prepared statement you have hardcoded into your PHP file? I have included the parts of the my PHP file that are relevant to this question. I am literally trying to overwrite whatever the user inputs is for a single string value with my hardcoded string. All of the values would then be inserted into a table in my database. In this case the value I am trying to overwrite is **$empid** which previously acquired its value from user input. Any suggestions, comments and advice would be greatly appreciated since I have only been studying PHP for a few weeks now.

Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee (EMPID, NAME, DATEHIRED, POSITION, SALARY,  DEPTCODE, CANHIRE, BOSSID) VALUES ('$empid', '$employee', '$date', '$position', '$salary', '$department', '$canhire', '$bossid')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO employee (EMPID) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $empid);

$empid='EMP2022';
$stmt->execute();


$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Well you can simply overwrite it `$empid='newvalue'`.. where is the problem?

Comment: I think you're already doing it yourself, with the line `$empid='EMP2022';`, only you need to do that before you run the `prepare` and `bind_param` functions, otherwise, the statement has already been prepared so `$stmt->execute();` doesn't care that you just set a new value for `$empid`.

Comment: @Bango that is completely incorrect. The value only needs to be set before `execute()`

Comment: Then maybe use a double quote for your string `$empid="EMP2022";` I don't actually know, otherwise I would write an answer, sorry if I tell you incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi Bounya, Bango, and Phil. Maybe I have been looking at this code for so long that I lost perspective. I will take what you wrote and try again. Thank you :D